# Laravel create database entery when hitting a route?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I'm still teaching myself laravel. I'm making an order form in laravel and i have a table full of products and i want to make it so that when make a new order and add the products. It would make its own order when i click new order it will make a new order number up and save it to the database?

Would the best way be to make an orders table with

```
Schema::create('westcoOrders', function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('orderNumber');
        $table->json('content');
        $table->tinyInteger('sent')->default(0);
        $table->tinyInteger('delivered')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    } );
```

or would it be better having a table multiple tables so i have one like the one above without the json entry and then have a westcoOrderItems table like this?

```
Schema::create('westcoOrderItems', function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->string('orderNumber');
        $table->string('quantity');
        $table->string('productName');
        $table->string('productCode');
        $table->string('price');
        $table->timestamps();
    } );
}
```

So then i have link the order number to the other table. Or is that a long way to go around it?
and if i do it that way i will have to find a way to make an order number when i hit the new order route?

I feel like I'm doing this the wrong/long way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, something like the following would be better:

```
// For orders
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->tinyInteger('is_delivered')->default(0);
    $table->tinyInteger('is_paid')->default(0);
    $table->timestamps();
});

// For ordered_items (one order may contain many products/ordered_items)
Schema::create('ordered_items', function (Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('order_id')->unsigned(); // fk for order.id
    $table->string('quantity')->unsigned();
    $table->string('productName');
    $table->string('productCode');
    $table->decimal('price', 10, 2);
});
```

Then the models, for example:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model {

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Item::class');
    }
}
```

The `Item` class for `ordered_items`:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Item extends Model {

    protected $table = 'ordered_items';

    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
    }
}
```

Hope you got the idea. This is the simplest one.

Comment: Thanks This is what i was looking for. The only other thing now is when i want to create a new order how am i going to create the new order entery??

Comment: Welcome! Well, you can use 'Order.create()' or other ways that laravel offers.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll use that. I'll let you know how I've got on

Comment: I have done all that an its works but.. I canno use the `retrun $this->belongsTo(westcoOrders::class);` Becuase it comes up with this error `syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE)`

Comment: You've syntax errors, check properly, also try `retrun $this->belongsTo('\App\westcoOrders');` like syntax.

Comment: Yeah i have changed it to that and now i cannot do it where i got to thr route of order/{ordernumber} when i do this its giving me the information in an array i think how can i get it so i can just place the product name?

Comment: Sorry i have the `{{ $items->westcoorderitems->first()->productName }}` and it wil only print the first product as it should. but i have it as just `{{ $items->westcoorderitems }}` it will print them all but like this '{"id":1,"westcoorder_id":1,"quantity":"3","productName":"3\/4\" FIXFI BRASS Y STRAINER","productCode":"735006","price":"4.58","created_at":"2016-03-18 21:29:06","updated_at":"2016-03-18 21:29:06"},'